# How to get application resource in Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I have an WPF application. This is application resources stored in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="wineRedBrush"
        Color="#B0324F" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="orangeBrush"
        Color="#F9694B" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="lightGray"
        Color="#D4D4D4" />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="darkGray"
        Color="#A8A8A8" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to get my lightGray brush from application resources in Generic.xaml:

```
<Separator
    Grid.Column="2"
    Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=wineRedBrush}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="10,4,12,0" />
```

But the resource can not be found, why? Is it possible to get it?

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: Yes, I do. Error: resource not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource?

```
<Separator
    Grid.Column="2"
    Background="{DynamicResource wineRedBrush}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Margin="10,4,12,0" />
```